# How to bypass WordPress redirect_canonical for a certain URL

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have a WordPress site and I made a folder inside the WordPress installation folder called `en`. So suppose if my site URL is `example.com` which loads my WordPress site, the visitor should can access the contents of `en` folder by visiting `example.com/en/` URL.

But unfortunately the WordPress redirects the visitor to a page with URL like `example.com/environmental-advertising/`, which is a blog post. [As I understood](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/redirect_canonical), WordPress's `redirect_canonical` causing this redirect.

So how can I prevent this type of redirects for a certain URLs like `example.com/en/`?

***UPD #1:** The `en` folder is **another WordPress installation**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `redirect_canonical` to tell the function to not use this url when try to find the page. Here is the code:

```
add_filter( 'redirect_canonical', 'custom_redirect_canonical', 10, 2 );
function custom_redirect_canonical( $redirect_url, $requested_url ) {
    if( $requested_url == 'http://example.com/en' ) {
        return $requested_url;
    }

    return $redirect_url;
}
```

Please note the following:

1. I do not recommend to use such function. It will be better if you change your folder name to something that `redirect_canonical` will skip.
2. The above code use hardcoded url which is also not a best practice.

Comment: The code didn't work. Still redirecting to that article. 
Does it make difference if the `en` folder, is another WordPress installation?

Comment: I don't think so. Can you please provide your real URL?
Also please make sure that the code is placed in `functions.php`

Comment: Yes the code placed in theme's `function.php` and changed the sample URL with the real one which is located in localhost.

Comment: Ok, and the `en` folder is placed in WordPress root directory where are wp-content, wp-admin etc? I ask because it works just fine on my localhost

Comment: Think it as a WordPress installation folder inside another one. like `wordpress/wordpress/`

Comment: Ok can you disable globally `redirect_canonical` by adding the following line  and check if the link works.

`remove_filter('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical'); `

Comment: Thanks, I create a new fresh WordPress installation inside that `en` folder, and now everything works fine.

Comment: @StanimirStoyanov How can I disable redirect on the front page but keep it for urls with /something? The scenario i want is to use a masked domain (maskeddomain.com) that redirects to domain.com (while keeping maskedomain.com in url). But when visiting root of maskeddomain.com i'm redirected to domain.com. I tried replacing example.com in your answer with maskedomain.com but i'm still getting redirected (while just returning false works except for /something urls also return a 404 page and not a page for example /something-cool)